# Is it possible to inject an enum into a classes scope/namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, typedef, using

With an enum `Foo::Values` and a class `Bar` outside of `Foo`, can I inject all values of the enum into class scope without redefining the type?

```
namespace Foo{
    enum Values{
        zero, one, two
    };
}

struct Bar{
    typedef Foo::Values Values; //Doesn't work, but is what I'd like to do
    using Foo::Values;          //Or this
}
```

So that these are valid:

```
Foo::Values val = Bar::zero;
assert(std::is_same<Foo::Values, Bar::Values>::value);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If you change it to a scoped enumeration, then the `typedef` will do what you want.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to use a scoped enum in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way:

```
using Values = Foo::Values;
```

Extracting the values is possible only one by one:

```
static constexpr Values zero = Foo::zero;
static constexpr Values one = Foo::one;
static constexpr Values two = Foo::two;
```

Check:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace Foo {
    enum Values { zero, one, two };
}

struct Bar {
    using Values = Foo::Values;
    static constexpr Values zero = Foo::zero;
    static constexpr Values one = Foo::one;
    static constexpr Values two = Foo::two;
};

int main() {
    Foo::Values val = Bar::zero;
    std::cout << std::is_same<Foo::Values, Bar::Values>::value;
}
```

Output:

> 1

Comment: Perfect solution. VS2013 doesn't have support for `constexpr` yet, so I just used `const`, which doesn't make a functional difference. I guess when the programm runs it will use a tiny bit more memory, but I can certainly live with that.